# Get Cimg image buffer

Tags: c++, itk, cimg

I write a code to convert Cimg image to ITK image. I want to get the buffer from my Cimg image to do that. What should i do to get the buffer from a CImg image?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What's CImg, I assume it's some image processing package format?

Comment: Yes, it's defines classes and methods to manage images in c++.

Comment: OK, I don't know if it's possible to read buffer from CImg in ITK. But ITK is able to read from openCV buffer using a bridge class. An workaround to your problem is to communicate both in a raw file.